# Como simular o evento click em um <select> ao passar o mouse em cima de uma <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<div class="selectOptions">
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

e o seguinte código jQuery:

```
    $(".selectOptions").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(".selectOptions select").trigger('click');
    });
```

Meu objetivo é, ao passar o mouse `mouseover` sobre a `div`, abrir o `select`.

Existe uma maneira de fazer isso? Como? Da forma que estou fazendo não está funcionando.

Comment: Os browsers não permitem isto, então não é possível.

Comment: Tobias, trem referencia dessa negativa para eu estudar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível simular um click no elemento `<select>`, porém existe uma forma de expandi-lo transformando-o em um `listBox` inserindo no `<select>` o atributo `size`:

```
$("#select").attr('size',3);
```

Adicionei também um evento `mouseout` para redefinir o `<select>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".selectOptions")
 .on("mouseover", function() {
  $("#select").attr('size',3)
    .addClass("expandido")
    .css("position","absolute");
 })
 .on("mouseout", function() {
  $("#select").attr('size',1)
    .css("position","relative");
 });
});
```

```css
.expandido option{
padding: 0 10px;
}

.expandido option:hover{
background: blue;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectOptions" style="display: block; width: 100px; background: red; height: 30px;">
  Bla Bla
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Adicionei um `class` para melhor apresentação.

Comment: Pois é, mas como seria se temos uma div aí que não está sendo levando em conta a sua altura?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Não entendi. Pelo código informado, essa div não tem altura, ou melhor, a altura a div é a altura do select que tem dentro dela.

Comment: sim, não tem. dessa forma, quando o select abre, ele fica encolhido dentro da div, entende.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Entendi agora. A div tem uma altura fixa, é isso?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Ou melhor, não entendi. O select, quando abre, não respeita a altura da div em que ele está inserido.

Comment: Exatamente isso. Ele precisa sobrepassar, senão não podemos ver as opções uma vez que não trem como calcular o height da div pelo tamanho do número das lis pela sua altura

Comment: @CarlosRocha Fiz uma alteração no código. Dá uma olhada lá e veja se era alguma coisa assim que vc está falando.

Comment: só retirar o height da div

Answer (score 1):

tenta usar esta função:

```
$('select').hover(function() {

  $(this).attr('size', $('option').length);
}, function() {

  $(this).attr('size', 1);
});
```

demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avdavQ

Answer (score 0):

JS puro.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drop on Hover</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DropList() {
            var n = document.getElementById("sel").options.length;
            document.getElementById("sel").size = n;
        }
    </script>
    <style>
     select option:hover {
          background-color: #555;
          color: white;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       <select id="sel" onmouseover="DropList()" onmouseout="this.size=1;">
            <option>Um</option>
            <option>Dois</option>
            <option>Três</option> 
            <option>Quatro</option> 
            <option>Cinco</option>
            <option>Seis</option>
            <option>Sete</option>
            <option>Oito</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```